# Redux Form submit values without hitting submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am pretty sure that there is a way to do this with onChange, but in the example: http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/simple/ here provided by redux form when you click the drop down and hit a value it automatically submits the value without having to hit submit.

I copied the exact code and everything works except for the fact that I have to choose all the values I want then hit submit. How do we make it to where we can just start typing in a field or select a value and it automatically get submitted as they have.

I will put the code below incase you do not want to visit the link.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
const  { DOM: { input, select, textarea } } = React

const SimpleForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="firstName" component={input} type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="lastName" component={input} type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="email" component={input} type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Sex</label>
        <div>
          <label><Field name="sex" component={input} type="radio" value="male"/> Male</label>
          <label><Field name="sex" component={input} type="radio" value="female"/> Female</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Favorite Color</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="favoriteColor" component={select}>
            <option></option>
            <option value="ff0000">Red</option>
            <option value="00ff00">Green</option>
            <option value="0000ff">Blue</option>
          </Field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="employed">Employed</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="employed" id="employed" component={input} type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Notes</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="notes" component={textarea}/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm)
```

Comment: do u want to submit the form on each keystroke?

Comment: I want exactly what they have. So you see the value as soon as you type or as soon as you check or select something!

Comment: to do that you just display what is in the redux store. The form automatically should update your store so then just display those values where ever you want

Comment: Could you elaborate or show the code. I am pretty new to redux form sorry

Comment: have you managed to set up redux ?

Comment: I have the reducers set up and the store and everything set up I believe. Do I need to do something like `onChange={action here to update store}` on each one?

Comment: Yes, you need to add an `onChange={handleSubmit}` to any field that you want to submit the form when they change the value

Comment: Okay and that should be it? something like `onChange={handleSubmit(this.submitPage.bind(this))}` and the `submitPage` function would do something like `submitPage(values){console.log(values)}` and I should get what they have?